# Fix hackish SQL where clause

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have two tables, `activities` and `activity_tours`.  `activities` hasMany `activity_tours` and are related by `activities.id` > `activity_tours.activity_id`. I have written the following SQL to select rows in both the tables having either of two conditions.

1. if it has a certain `activity_tours.tour_type` OR
2. the activity has more than one tour

The query seems a bit hackish. Could someone help me make this query more efficient.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    activities.activity_name,
    activities.image_path,
    activity_tours.tour_type
FROM
    activities
    LEFT JOIN activity_tours ON activities.id = activity_tours.activity_id
WHERE
    (
        activity_tours.tour_type != 17 OR (
            (SELECT count(*) FROM activity_tours WHERE activity_id = activities.id) > 1)
    )
```

Comment: Please add the the create sql statements for the concerned tables. That would help in understanding the data model better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.activity_name,
    a.image_path,
    at.tour_type,
    MAX(at.tour_type != 17) AS tour_not_17,
    COUNT(*) AS tour_count
FROM activities a
INNER JOIN activity_tours at ON a.id = at.activity_id
GROUP BY a.activity_name, a.image_path
HAVING tour_not_17 OR tour_count > 1
```

Didn't know what to do with the `tour_type` column; an aggregate should be used, but I couldn't figure out which one. Perhaps you could do `GROUP_CONCAT()` ?